# Decryption returning "NullException" error when run

Tags: c#, encryption

all.
I've set up a file in a winforms project which needs an encrypted string, and i'm using the nuget plugin MirzaCryptoHelpers ([here](https://github.com/mirzaevolution/MirzaCryptoHelpersV2/wiki/MirzaCryptoHelpers.SymmetricCryptos)), which is a wrapper for common decryption/encryption methods. I'm trying to decrypt a previously encrypted file, however it is returning a NullException upon attempting to convert the decrypted bytes back to a string.

Here's my method:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\file.txt")
encryptedstring = sr.ReadLine();
sr.Close() //finished using reader.

//Converting string to bytes.
byte[] encryptedbytes = BitHelpers.ConvertStringToBytes(encryptedstring);
//Decrypting bytes, returns "null" for unknown reason
byte[] unencryptedbytes = new AESCrypto().Decrypt(encryptedbytes, "pass");

//Error is thrown on the below line:
string finalbytes = BitHelpers.ConvertBytesToString(unencryptedbytes);
```

What's wrong with my method? Or is it the plugin i'm using?

Comment: did you debug the values inside `encryptedstring`, `encryptedbytes`, `unencryptedbytes? check them for null? if so, its more reasonable to look for the errro inside `Bithelpers.ConvertBytesToString`

Comment: I've debugged the values, and unencryptedbytes turns up as null also. So, the error's actually in the decryption.

Comment: `encryptedstring` is filled?

Comment: `encryptedstring` is indeed filled, as it converts to `encryptedbytes`, which has 29 values in it's array.

Comment: So, I found this in the AESCrypto Decrypt function as a comment: `//returns null if decryption failed.` It has something to do with a faulty key or iv.

Comment: ReadLine() will remove line termination characters. Might be you need them for the decryption to work...

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Using "ReadToEnd" instead.

Comment: My advice to anyone who encounters the same issue with Mirza: Change to csharp-aes. The link can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/czubehead/csharp-aes), and it's much easier to implement, and works properly.